# bash function - use . character as parameter

Tags: bash, git

I am trying to create a personalized function to wrap `git add`.

Since I'm not a bit fan of having to type `git add a/long/path/to/some/file/that/has/changed.java` I am trying to create some sort of fuzzy matching function so that I just have to type a part of the filename and add all matching filenames, for example `gadd ged` would match the file above.

My `gadd` function is:

```
# wildcard git add
function gadd
{
    if [ ! -z "$1" ]; then
        command git add *$1*
        cls #some other function that actually works
    else
        echo $'No wildcard specified, doing nothing.'
    fi
}
```

But that does not seem to work with the dot character (`git add .`) that adds all changed files.

What should I try?

Comment: I am on Linux. I am by no means an expert but I read that by using $1 I can reference the parameter passed to the function from the terminal. Is this mistaken? The * signs are wildcard operators for `git` and actually work fine with all strings except `.`.

Comment: The `$1` is indeed the first parameter.  How would calling `gadd ged` call `git add a/long/path/to/some/file/that/has/changed.java` with your current function?  Where does that translation take place?

Comment: My understanding is that `command git add *$1*` will execute `git add *$1*`, so in the case of `gadd ged` it will execute `git add *ged*`. `git` allows the use of wildcards for file matching so `git add *ged*` matches (and adds) the file `a/long/path/to/some/file/that/has/changed.java`.

Comment: How does it guess where the file is?  I suppose you're trying this from the `a/long/path/to/some/file/that/has/` directory but that doesn't fit with your question if you need to pass the long path that you don't want to type.

Comment: `git` allows you to use wildcards as shown [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#Pathspecs)

Comment: Use "" (quote) with $1!!

Comment: @anpel:  I get that `git` supports wildcard, but it doesn't support magic guessing where the file you're thinking of is located on the drive.

Comment: @pbies I just tried that! It works! Please format it as an answer so that I can accept in case someone reads this.

Comment: @JuliePelletier if in the command line you execute `git add *ged*` it locates any matching files e.g. file paths that start with anything, then the string `ged` followed by anything. It will match `a/long/path/to/some/file/that/has/changed.java`, `a/gedit/file.txt` and pretty much anything with `ged` in the filename. There is no magic guessing involved (or there is, I don't really know `git` internals).

Comment: Try changing directories and running it again and you'll get what I'm saying.  This can not work.

Comment: @JuliePelletier it works for any directory within the project, from any directory within the project. How `git` actually does that is beyond the scope of the question. I only wanted to know if the `.` character could be escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use "" (quote) with $1, it may help.

So it would be looking as "*$1*".